# Check if user selected all in shiny pickerInput menu

Tags: r, input, shiny, selection

I have a shiny application with several pickerInput menus. They amount of choices change in each menu based on the selections of other menus so I can't ever hard code anything (ex: menu A will have 4 total selections possible).

I am trying to determine how to check if the user selected all of the possible values in a menu (pickerInput has a built in Select All button).

An example of how my pickerInput menus are structured:

```
choices <- c("apple", "pear", "orange")    
pickerInput(inputId = "A",
            label = "Menu A:",
            choices = c(sort(na.omit(choices))),
            options = list(`actions-box` = T,
                           `none-selected-text` = "Please make a selection."),
            multiple = T)
```

In the above code example there are (hard coded) 3 choices, however, in my real app this may vary. In this example, to find out if all choices were selected, I could simply check if 3 selections were stored in `input$A`.

I am looking to generalize this, I checked the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyWidgets/versions/0.4.4/topics/pickerInput) and am not finding any built-in way of checking if a user selected all of the choices in a `pickerInput` menu. So I am looking for an alternative way of checking this.

Comment: couldnt you have a list with the choices for each pickerinput and the names of that list would be the id of the pickerinput. In your case `choiceList <- list("A" = choices)`. And then you could check `choiceList[[input[["A"]]]] %in% input[["A"]]`.